# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentDay' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a textfield1 and a textfield in a modal, When I click on textfield1 it appears fine, but when I click on the textfield present in the modal the datepicker appears but on selecting the date gives this error
[image]

After much googling and searching about same error I found that it could be because of same IDs of textfield but i ensured that both have different IDs,
I dont know what is actually causing the problem
Here is my code

```
      <script>
$(function() {
    $("body").delegate("#tx1, #tx2", "focusin", function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});

  </script>
```

**EDIT**
These are the libraries

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: which is the modal and datepicker libraries used and whether the modal is loaded dunamically

Comment: @ArunPJohny it is loaded on click

Comment: which are the libraries used? is it jQuery UI

Comment: @ArunPJohny i made an edit

Comment: Try only with this `<script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the cause for the problem,

```
<!-- Make sure the file path is correct -->
<script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
```

or use CDN links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

remove the other **script** files.

I have tested in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xCa8E/), you code is working fine.

Comment: no this is not, things only get when we introduce modal,you js fiddle doens't contain modal

Comment: In the console log it is showing error and also telling line #, so file inclusion is not issue here